# Git SVN checkouts branches in a wrong directory

Tags: git, svn

I have a SVN repo with following structure:

```
Root
+ Dir1
+---src1
+ Dir2
+---src2
+ Dir3
+---src3
```

There is a brach mybranch, created from Dir2, which contains only src2. I attached the branch to my Git SVN with following commands:

```
git config --add svn-remote.mybranch.url url/branches/mybranch
git config --add svn-remote.mybranch.fetch :refs/remotes/mybranch
git svn fetch mybranch
git checkout -b local-mybranch -t mybranch
```

It all passes with no issues, but the result is undesired. The Dir2 becomes root and it is merged with the root of the whole repo:

```
Root
+ Dir1
+---src1
+ Dir2
+---src2
+ Dir3
+---src3
+ src2
```

You can see that the src2 directory is put in the root and not in the Dir2.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I obviously completely misunderstood the philosophy of SVN - I was expecting the same behaviour as GIT provides. The thing I thought was a problem, was a normal behaviour of SVN...